# How to fetch id in blade template in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to fetch this id 9 in blade
            http://localhost/connect/public/index.php/profile/9
i dont want to route it

Comment: it means you don't want to use routes?

Comment: i have routed id my main problem is i am not able fetch the user detais in blade so . i want to fetch id from url

Comment: can you paste your code ?

Comment: Route::get('/profile/{profile}',[
 'uses' => 'ProfileController@profile',
 'as' => 'post.user',
 'middleware' => 'auth'
 ]);

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your profilecontroller your method is like this

```
public function profile($profile){
  // you can call model function and get data from profile id 
 //and then pass it to the view
$data["profile_info"] = "fetch the data from database call your model function "; 
 return View("your_bladefilename",$data);

}
```

you can access profile_info in your blade file using profile_info variable

in your blade file

```
<?php 

    print_r($profile_info);

?>
```

Let me know if anything is not clear

Comment: i think your issue is in routes

Comment: have you echo "here"; and exit in your profile method of ProfileController??

Comment: public function profile($profile){
    //$post = User::where('id',$profile)->first();
     $user = new User();
     $user = User::where('id',$profile)->first();
     //$user
     //dd($user);
     

    echo $user->first_name;
     echo $user->id;
     
    
    return view('profile');
       
   }

Comment: $data["profile_info"] = $user;
 return view("profile",$data);

Comment: you can pass the data in view file like this did u get any errors??

Comment: i  got the out put but how can i decorate it in my blade i.e name = here i should get name; i am getting output in arrays

Comment: its in object you will get it like this  i.e $profile_info->name